# ToggleClass not working on live site, but works on staging?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, toggleclass

I have a Wordpress powered site, that runs a plugin called UberMenu.  As part of modifications to the plugin, I have made some CSS changes to the mobile variation of the menu.

Whilst on mobile, I have set up a very basic toggleClass jQuery code, which toggles a class called "close", which in turn changes the small icon on the right, that is set by CSS:after.

This works a treat on staging:

http://tulaforlife.staging.wpengine.com/
(open site on mobile, tap 'menu', then tap 'products'.  note the + sign change to a minus on tap, and back again on close).

I can't however get it working on live:

http://www.tula.com

It just won't toggle the class for the same CSS.  Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 jQuery('.menu-button-text').attr("onclick","return true");



 jQuery('.ubermenu-target').on ('touchstart', function() {
jQuery(this).toggleClass('close');
jQuery('.ubermenu-target').not(this).removeClass('close');
});
 jQuery('.ubermenu-target').hover(function () {
jQuery(this).toggleClass("close");
 });

});
</script>
```

CSS:

```
span.ubermenu-target.ubermenu-item-layout-default.ubermenu-item-layout-text_only:after {
 content:"\f067" !important;
}

span.ubermenu-target.ubermenu-item-layout-default.ubermenu-item-layout-text_only.close:after  {
content:"\f068" !important;
}
```

Interestingly, if I change the target of the touchstart in the jQuery to ".ubermenu-target-title" it does toggle the class in the HTML (but only when the actual text is tapped), but it just won't do it for the .ubermenu-target, which is what I want it to do.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong, and why it works on staging but won't work on live? :(

Comment: what role has `jQuery('.menu-button-text').attr("onclick","return true");` ?,

Comment: Sorry I think that's unrelated - didn't see that.

Comment: where is the click event for your toggle i see only a hover event?

Comment: .on('touchstart') is the touch event (on mobile, it's only for mobile view).  It works fine on staging, just not live.  Incidentally it doesn't work on hover either (if I resize screen on desktop browser to mobile size).

Comment: you realize that mobiles don't have hover?,why don't you use a click event?

Comment: The hover is just for those who are on a desktop but resize their browser to mobile size (the Wordpress theme adds a hover automatically, so I've put that there to toggle the class still).

I tried a click event but it didnt work on mobile, as mobile is touch ;)  It works fine on staging, so I know the actual JS code works, but it doesn't register the touch event on the live site, with the same code.

Comment: it seems your class isn't toggling at all ,your event isn't bind properly

Comment: Yes I know, that's why I'm asking for help :p

Comment: use event delegation or change the selector

Comment: Whats event delegation?  Could you explain how to do it in the code I have?